# How to return the subclasses of generic type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, generic-programming

I have this classes:

```
public abstract class Parent {}
public class Child extends Parent{}
```

I made the class Connector where i want that T type will assume the subclasses of Parent:

```
public class Connector <T extends Parent>{
    T t;
    public Connector(T t){
        this.t=t;
    }
    public T getObject(T t){
        Child p = new Child();
        return (T) p;       
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
Child c1  = new Child();
Connector<Parent> cConnector = new Connector<Parent>(c1);
Child c2 = cConnector.getObject(c1);
```

Everything works with the cast, but I don't understand why I have to add a cast to what's being returned in the `getObject` method if the T extends Parent

Comment: Consider `public class Child2 extends Parent{}`. Your code breaks with a `ClassCastException`. The question is: What do you want to do here? Why does `getObject` take a `T` as parameter?

Comment: @tunaki  the getObject take T as parameter because i want to do operations on the subclasses of Parent

Comment: @joumvaer92 You can do that if you just simply return `t` after operating on it, but you can't just assume that `t` will always be of type `Child` so that's why you need a cast to return an object of type `Child`, but I would consider just returning `t` and making `t` of type `Child` when constructing the `Connector`

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between local `Child p` variable and generic type `T` you've introduced in `Connector`. Neither field `T t` nor parameter `T t` are being used in `getObject` method hence an explicit cat is required.

If you provide the following `getObject` implementation:

```
public T getObject(){
    return t;       
}
```

there is no need for the cast anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `T` assumes no connection with the `Child` class. Make another class called `Pet` that extends `Parent`,

```
public class Pet extends Parent{
    ...
}
```

Now let's revisit your `getObject` method. Replace all instances of T with `Pet`,

In the main, we now have

```
Pet p  = new Pet();
Connector<Pet> cConnector = new Connector<Pet>(p);
```

In the Connector class,

```
//** symbol is used as placeholder, not actually part of the code
public *Pet* getObject(*Pet* t){
    Child p = new Child();
    return (*Pet*) p;       
}
```

The reason why the cast is needed is that there is no guarantee that `Pet` and `Child` are related. If the cast were omitted then an object of type `Child` would have been returned when the return type was `Pet`, which causes an error since `Pet` doesn't equal `Child`. If you want to return a new object of type `Child` then I'd suggest doing something like this (parameter can be omitted since you weren't using it before),

```
public Child getObject(){
     Child p = new Child();
     return p;
}
```

or

```
public Child getObject(T t){
     //do operations on t here
     return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `getObject` method you create instance of `Child` when result should be any child of `Parent`. This code will break if you try to use it with any other type `AnotherChild extends Parent`

Solution to this problem would be to pass a factory method for child object.

```
public class Connector <T extends Parent>{
    Supplier<T> factory;
    T t;
    public Connector(T t, Supplier<T> factory){
        this.t=t;
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public T getObject(T t){
        return factory.get();
    }
}
```

then usage would look like

```
Child someChild = new Child();
Connector<Child> connector = new Connector<>(someChild, Child::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Everything works with the cast", of course, it works but it is error-prone, by the way, you use generic type, the wrong way.

when you are write:

```
<T extends Parent>
```

It means that your class accepts every type T that is a subclass of Parent. to make it more clear, see this code:

```
public class FruitBaskets<T extends Fruit>{
T t;
public addFruit(T t){
    this.t=t;
}
public T getFruit(T t){
    return t;       
    }
}

FruitBasket<Apple> myFuitBasket = new FruitBasket();
```

Because in your class definition, you made it clear that you accept types that extend from fruit, so don`t need to worry about about obj added or retrieved from your fruit basket (no casting is needed), cause if somebody tries to add a dog into your fruitbasket, he will get a compile-time exception and you can catch and fix it and prevent a runtime exception.